# CSS not refreshing on JSP page even after adding more lines and clearing cache. After clearing cache on Chrome none of the CSS pages are working

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

Everything seemed to work properly after I added a couple of lines of CSS to a stylesheet that already worked, and it would not refresh and include the new lines, it would only show the ones from before.

After trying to clear the cache on Chrome, none of the pages seem to load the CSS pages or any Google Fonts that I linked, but when I open a new project everything loads up, and I am lost, any help would be appreciated!

I am using Intellij as my IDE ( JSP pages, Java, Servlet, CSS )

File Structure:
webapp -> pages -> html -> css *( css inside html inside pages inside webapp )*

My header:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/shop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/base.css">

    <!-- Fonts Lato & Montserrat -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;500;700;900&family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <title>Store</title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with Versioning:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/shop.css?version=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/base.css?version=1">
```

if you add new lines in your CSS then you change it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/shop.css?version=2">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/base.css?version=2">
```

and the Browser will load the CSS files again.

ADDITIONALLY you can add this code in your JSP file in the HTML Header for no-chache (but you must do the css Versioning also):

```
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache"); //Forces caches to obtain a new copy of the page from the origin server
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store"); //Directs caches not to store the page under any circumstance
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //Causes the proxy cache to see the page as "stale"
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0 backward compatibility
%>
```